# Pre-Requisite for Graphs for a directed acyclic graph

Tags: data-structures

Every tree is a directed, acyclic graph (DAG), but there exist DAGs that are not trees.
    a)  How can we tell whether a given DAG is a tree?
    b)  Devise an algorithm to test whether a given DAG is a tree??

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: No I have an exam in Sunday and I need the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that there are exactly `n - 1` edges(where `n` is the number of vertices).
2. Check that there is a vertex with zero indegree.
3. Run depth first search from this vertex and check that all vertices are reachable from it.

If at least one of this condition does not hold true, it is not a tree. Otherwise, it is a tree.

Comment: Is 2 required, given that it is already known that it's a DAG?

Comment: @harold Yes, it is redundant.